# 'Publish' missing in SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page, branding

When I try to publish a new master page in SharePoint Designer 2010, the publish options are missing.

[no 'publish' menu option http://www.acadiau.ca/~tammy/20194.png](http://www.acadiau.ca/~tammy/20194.png)

Also, I can't do anything from the Master Page gallery within SharePoint as the needed options are greyed out:

[greyed out http://www.acadiau.ca/~tammy/20198.jpg](http://www.acadiau.ca/~tammy/20198.jpg)

Troubleshooting thus far:

1. In central Administration | SharePoint Designer Settings | All services are enabled
2. Site Actions | Site Settings | Site Collection Administration | SharePoint Designer Settings | All services are enabled
3. I am Site Collection Administrator
4. SharePoint Server Publishing and SharePoint Server Standard site features are active
5. In Library settings | Versioning settings, 'require content approval for submitted items' and 'create a version each time you edit an item' are both turned on

Any suggestions as to what else to check?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You might not have enabled the "**SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure**" feature in SharePoint 2010. Enable this feature in *Site collection feature*

Comment: Thanks Paddy but I just checked and it was enabled.

Comment: "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" must be activated on the site collection and the actual subweb you're working with, is it set in both places (two separate features, one in Site Collection Features and one in Site Features).

Comment: Yes, thanks.  It's activated in both places (under Site Collection Administration -> Site Collection features as well as Site Actions -> Manage site features).

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer , but could be the reason.

Is the MasterPage checked-in with Major Version Or Minor ??

Comment: I'm not quite sure.  Does it only become a Major Version once it's published and since I don't have that capability, would it be considered Minor?

Comment: Its the other way, only a Major version File(Master page) can be published , go to the master page gallery and check the version history. check-in into Major Version and then publish.

Comment: I can check-in but no option to check-into a Major Version and publish.  When I click on the page, it opens up Library Tools->Documents tab and all but 3 options are greyed out.  [link](http://www.acadiau.ca/~tammy/master%20page%20gallery%20view.png).  The others report "This control is currently disabled. You might not have the right permission level to use this, you might need to select an object or item, or the control might not work in this context." I can't select an item.  When right click an item [link](http://www.acadiau.ca/~tammy/check%20in%20view%20from%20master%20page%20gallery.png)

Comment: Seems like a permission issue from screen shot, Even the "New Document" option is disabled

Could you please check the permission of the logged in user, I know you have mentioned as "Site collection Admin" ; but I guess the permission model might have been broken for this library. can you perform the following steps and let me know the results.

-> Goto the Master page Gallery.......
-> Goto on Library -> Library Permissions.......
-> Click on Check Permissions Options and enter the logged in the User ID , then click "Check Now" and let us know the results ( Screen shot would be great)

Comment: Sure - we had checked that for both myself and Farm Admin (different results for permissions however same results when we tried to Publish - i.e. same greyed out options) and everything appeared ok.  Here's the screenshot for my permission check: [My Permissions](http://www.acadiau.ca/~tammy/my%20permissions.png)