# Why isn't my Master Page visible in Designer when I deploy it from Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page, visual-studio-2012

In a VS 2012 project I created "TestMasterPage.master" (a duplicate of v4.master) and added it to a module named "Module_MasterPage" below are contents of elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="Module_MasterPage" List="116" Url="_catalogs/masterpage">
    <File Path="Module_MasterPage\TestMasterPage.master" Url="TestMasterPage.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="FALSE" />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

After deployment "TestMasterPage.master" shows up in the Master Page Gallery

[image]

So why not in SharePoint Designer?

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: did you already published it from the browser?

Comment: Thank you @L.V.SharepointArchitect for pointing me in the right direction.  See answer below

Answer (score 1):

I'm indebted to this exchange [Publish missing in Sharepoint Designer 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21273/publish-missing-in-sharepoint-designer-2010) where @webdes03 explained: "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" must be activated on the site collection and the actual subweb you're working with, it is set in both places (two separate features, one in Site Collection Features and one in Site Features).

All looks good after turning on ***BOTH*** publishing features
[image]